# Configuring wildcard record on AWS route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, nameservers, bluehost

I have a domain registered with Google Domains and using AWS Route 53 as NS.
This domain has several sub domains (some for our applications, and some for our public site)

*.dev.mydomain.com ('A' record pointing to a cloudfront for our development application) works great,
*.app.mydomain.com ('A' record pointing to a cloudfront for our live application) works great

[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) ('A' record pointing to an IP address on Bluehost which hosts our Wordpress website) works great

The one I can't figure out is how to get mydomain.com (without any subdomain) to point to the same Bluehost wordpress site as www.
I configured:

*.mydomain.com ('A' record pointing to the same bluehost IP)

But what I get is:

> This site can’t be reached
> mydomain.com’s server IP address could not
> be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that your public hosted zone is for `mydomain.com` you simply create the record without the subdomain part.

By using `*.mydomain.com` it will simply resolve any single level subdomain that does not have an explicit record to resolve to the bluehost IP.

If you're using the console and if you do not enter any value in the domain entry box you will default to creating a record for the apex/root domain record.

**Steps**

Click create record, you will then be presented with some options. Click "Define Simple Record", then fill in the details similar to the ones below. You should notice nothing filled in for the domain.

[image]

Click "Define Simple Record", then click "Create Records". You should now have your root domain records created.

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you. That worked. To be clear I created a 'A' record for [  ].mydomain.com (leaving the field fully blank. And set as an "Alias to another record in this hosted zone" and selected my www.mydomain.com as the destination. Waited a couple of minutes and it worked! Thank you!